# How to update the attribute related to Exchange like the proxyAddresses and the extensionAttribute1 using Microsoft Graph

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, office365-restapi

I want to update the proxyAddresses and extensionAttribute1 using Microsoft Graph.
However , proxyAddresses is for read-only, extensionAttribute1 is because it does not exist in https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata, can not be updated .

It will actually result in an error .

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/test01@test.onmicrosoft.com
{
    "proxyAddresses": [
        "SMTP:test01@test.onmicrosoft.com",
        "smtp:test01-2@test.onmicrosoft.com"
    ]
}

response:
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Request_BadRequest",
        "message": "Property 'proxyAddresses' is read-only and cannot be set.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "84c5ca8e-47ad-44e3-b98f-e6c37f9139b7",
            "date": "2016-06-22T15:53:35"
        }
    }
}


PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/test01@test.onmicrosoft.com
{
    "extensionAttribute1": "aaa"
}

response:
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Request_BadRequest",
        "message": "One or more extension property values specified are invalid.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "cdd06584-70a8-4c82-8fa7-be520c28c0ee",
            "date": "2016-06-22T15:51:57"
        }
    }
}
```

Please tell me if there is a way to update.

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide some scenario information on why you need to update proxyAddresses please?

For extensionAttributes, this is something we are looking to expose in Microsoft Graph shortly.  However these are likely to be read-only too for now, since this would be data mastered in on-premises AD and sync'd to the cloud.

We have other mechanisms (under [/beta](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/extensionproperty) and in [Azure AD Graph API for registering schema extensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-directory-schema-extensions) that you can get/set as a general extensibility model).

Hope this helps,

Comment: Not to hijack this question, but it would be helpful to be able to update the proxyAddresses via the Graph API directly.  When you create a mailbox in EXO it doesn't appear to sync the proxy addresses to Azure AD immediately so if you license them Azure AD will push the incorrect proxyAddresses back to the EXO object.